# clang format space before parens in function call except for short names like gettext helpers?

Tags: c, code-formatting, clang-format

An example of a common style pattern is:

```c
return g_strdup (_("24-hour"));

label = g_strdup_printf (C_("timezone desc", "%s (%s)"), ...
```

I.e. space between function name and opening parenthesis, but *not* when the function is a translation helper like `_` or `C_`. Because it looks silly to have an `_` floating by itself...

Does clang-format have such an ability?

I guess a feature to support that style could be based on excepting specific function names from the space rule, or by not having the space if the function name is short (by some definition).